# Server returned HTTP response code: 523 for URL: http

Tags: java, html, http, networking

I want to crawl a webpage, the request type is post,but I get an error:
java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 523 for URL: http://

```
public static String readContentFromPost(String urlStr, String content) {
    URL url = null;
    HttpURLConnection con = null;
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();

    try {
        url = new URL(urlStr);
        con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        con.setDoOutput(true);
        con.setDoInput(true);
        con.setRequestMethod("POST");
        con.setUseCaches(false);
        con.setInstanceFollowRedirects(true);
        con.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "text/html;charset=utf-8");
        con.connect();

        DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(con.getOutputStream());
        out.writeBytes(content);

        out.flush();
        out.close();

        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                con.getInputStream()));

        String line;
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that parameter `urlStr` is correct?

Answer (score 1):

The error 523 doesn't have any standard meaning: http://www.iana.org/assignments/http-status-codes/http-status-codes.xhtml

So it's a propietary error of the server you're trying to crawl... Try to contact the web administrator to know what it means.

523 doesn't mean Unreachable origin... it only means that in Cloudflare:
https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200171946-Error-523-Origin-is-unreachable

Try your code with a well-know server like Google or Wikipedia in order to know if it works fine.

Comment: Thanks！I will try to simulation the browser to get the data

Answer (score 1):

To crawl a webPage which solve in javascript maybe can use selenium to simulation the browser to get the data.
selenium:http://www.seleniumhq.org

First create a maven Project and add:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
        <version>2.45.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

Then download a ChromeDriver:
http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=2.14/

and put it in the directory of /usr/local/bin

last you can crawl the page:

```
public static void testSelenium(String url) {
    // System.getProperties().setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","/Users/freezhan/IDE/tools/chromedriver");
    WebDriver webDriver = new ChromeDriver();

    webDriver.get(url);
    //WebElement webElement = webDriver.findElement(By.xpath("/html"));

    System.out.println(webDriver.getPageSource());

    webDriver.close();

}
```